# Why is Photo Stream not visible in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization, photo-stream

I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 12.1.4, and I recently noticed my photos are not being uploaded to Photo Stream. There is no option for Photo Stream under Settings app → Account → iCloud → Photos, nor under Settings app → Photos. Did this option get removed in iOS 12?

[image] [image]

Comment: No, the option is not removed in iOS 12.

Comment: Any idea why it's not showing in my screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with Apple, I learned they are phasing out Photo Stream.  Any new Apple IDs created since approximately 2018 don't have access to this feature.  Looks like I will have to start using iCloud Photos or some other sync utility.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317

Comment: Just so people know - if you are grandfathered in - there's no sign of it going away yet.  I'm using it on iOS 14 / Catalina and even in the pre-release betas so I get if not everyone can use it if they signed up after the transition to purely the iCcloud library.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and purchased a 2 TB cloud storage from Mac world for about $60, but later found out there are better storage solutions available.  Now I have to figure out how to synchronize my photos with all devices using this storage solution. I didn’t realize photo stream was being phased out, I really liked the convenience.

Comment: If you already have My Photo Stream, then it is still very much in evidence in iOs 14, and MacOS 11 Big Sur.

Comment: I'm with ben - the storage helps you whether your account used Photo Stream due to age or if your account was set up purely to store to the iCloud Photos storage buckets.